# How to remove side vinyl from the window

Tags: windows, siding, glass, window-frame

I live in a cold place. I already have double sided window but unfortunately, they are massive and basically make up the whole living room, thus making the living room very cold. I bought more double side window, each with the same size.

Anyways, I was about to install the double sided window and found out very quick that removing these plastic siding thingy are very hard:

[image]

I tried prying it, but it is so hard to get it in there. I tried knife, it works, but it bends, and I'm afraid that if I pry it too hard, I"ll crack the window. I can't find anything in the internet about this. I don't even know the name of that siding thingy. Just "vinyl siding"? In any case, that didn't yield any google results. Any help would bey very much appreciated.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do. By "double sided window" do you mean two-pane sealed units? What "thingy"? What's your goal? In my part of the world we don't modify window units like that--double-glazing is usually adequate.

Comment: My goal is to add another two-pane sealed unit. The only thing stopping that is the white vinyl, again don't know the name. I need to remove it in order to insert another 2 panes sealed units. Unfortunately, I have the misfortune of living in northern Canada where even in May, it is cold. I can only fantasize about living in rural Texas or Southern California, New Mexico or Arizona. Someday.

Comment: I think it is the window frame that was fitted during the window replacement. You might be able to see how it was placed/attached by search Youtube for "step-by-step guide to window installation", then reverse the procedure. Here is one. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yks01Ot2R5c

Comment: Wait, you want to add a _second_, double-glazed window unit, _inside_ the existing one? I really think you're going to be totally on your own on this - it's just not something that is normally done, so it's not going to be supported by any normal manufacturing process or readily available trim pieces to finish it off - you're going to be custom making everything. Not trying to be mean, but if "thingy" is the best term you've got to describe parts, making everything from scratch to support this install is likely beyond your current skill set.

Comment: It might be more expensive, but I'd suggest investigating double- or triple-pane replacement windows with low-e coatings and inert gas filling to increase the insulating value of the window units instead of trying to double up the glazing units themselves. If, of course, I've misunderstood you and this is _not_ what you're trying to do, then, by all means, ignore me, but please do try to clarify.

Comment: I'd be using window film during the cold months. Done right it's almost invisible, and it's cheap.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I thought replacing vinyl with vinyl requirrd.basically cutting a new opening.